# RGB-strip's color can't be controlled

Tags: c++, arduino, rgb, infrared

I have a huge problem with my Arduino controlling my RGB-LED Strip. I can controll the blue and green channel without any issues (all values from 0-255 are working) but my red channel is really not wanting to work... I can control it but it only goes on and off (0 and 255) but all other PWM frequencies won't work. It will just turn the LEDs off. The really weird thing is that I can eliminate that this might be happening because of a hardware failure because when I start a new sketch and just order the Arduino (Nano) to control the in the setup method every channel for every value works like a charm... Am I blind or what'S the problem with my code.

I really hope anyone of you can help me out.

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
//Pins for RGB LEDs
#define rotPin 11   //redLED
#define gruenPin 6 // green LED
#define blauPin 9 // blue LED

//EEPROM 0=red, 1=green, 2=blue 
int rVal, gVal, bVal;
boolean ersterStart = true;



//IR-recevier Stuff
const int RECV_PIN = A0;            // Pin of the IR-Receiver
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);        // defining of a receiver object
decode_results results;         // variable for saving the IR-results

//IR-Codes for the IR transmitter
#define on 16236607
#define off 16203967
#define dunkler 16220287
#define heller 16187647
#define rot 16195807
#define gruen 16228447
#define blau 16212127
#define weiss 16244767
#define hellrot 16191727
#define orange 16199887
#define orangebraun 16189687
#define gelb 16197847
#define dunkelgrün 16224367
#define hellesdunkelgrün 16232527
#define hellgrün 16222327
#define tuerkis 16230487
#define dunkelblau 16208047
#define ultramarine 16216207
#define dunkelviolett 16206007
#define violett 16214167
#define flash 16240687
#define strobe 16248847
#define fadebtn 16238647
#define smooth 16246807

//Variables for Fading (fade())
byte r, g, b;
char farbe = 'b';             // letter for current color (Blue)
int fadePause = 8;            // time for fading steps; smaller = faster, bigger = slower
int halteZeit = 500;          // pause time between colors
unsigned long fadeZeit = 0;   // variable for saving the current millis()
boolean ersterLauf = true;    // needed to check if it's the first run of the program
boolean fadeOn = false;       // defines if fademode should be turned on

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(rotPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(gruenPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(blauPin, OUTPUT);
    ersterLauf=true;
    irrecv.enableIRIn();          // initializes IR-receiver 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    if(EEPROM.read(3)==1){
        fadeOn=true;
    }
    else{
        fadeOn=false;
    }
    if(fadeOn == false){
        analogWrite(rotPin,EEPROM.read(0));
        analogWrite(gruenPin,EEPROM.read(1));
        analogWrite(blauPin,EEPROM.read(2));
    }

}


void loop(){
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
                                        //IR-basecodes
        if(results.value == on){

            analogWrite(rotPin, EEPROM.read(0));
            analogWrite(gruenPin, EEPROM.read(1));  //load RGB values from EEPROM
            analogWrite(blauPin, EEPROM.read(2));

            irrecv.resume();
        }

        if(results.value == off){   //turns all LEDs off

            analogWrite(rotPin,0);
            analogWrite(gruenPin,0);
            analogWrite(blauPin,0);

            irrecv.resume();
        }

        if(results.value == weiss){ // turns on white color

            analogWrite(rotPin,255);
            analogWrite(gruenPin,255);
            analogWrite(blauPin,255);

            EEPROM.write(0,255);
            EEPROM.write(1,255);
            EEPROM.write(2,255);

            irrecv.resume();
        }

        if(results.value == rot){   // turns on red color

            analogWrite(rotPin,255);
            analogWrite(gruenPin,0);
            analogWrite(blauPin,0);

            EEPROM.write(0,255);
            EEPROM.write(1,0);
            EEPROM.write(2,0);

            irrecv.resume();
        }

        if(results.value == gruen){ // turns on green color

            analogWrite(rotPin,0);
            analogWrite(gruenPin,255);
            analogWrite(blauPin,0);

            EEPROM.write(0,0);
            EEPROM.write(1,255);
            EEPROM.write(2,0);

            irrecv.resume();
        }

        if(results.value == blau){  // turns on blue color

            analogWrite(rotPin,0);
            analogWrite(gruenPin,0);
            analogWrite(blauPin,255);

            EEPROM.write(0,0);
            EEPROM.write(1,0);
            EEPROM.write(2,255);

            irrecv.resume();
        }

        irrecv.resume();
    }

    if(Serial.available() > 0){

        delay(500);                     // Serial Input Base-Code

        if(Serial.peek() == 'r'){   //controls red color (not working properly)

            Serial.read();
            rVal = Serial.parseInt();
            analogWrite(rotPin, rVal);
            EEPROM.write(0, rVal);
        }

        if(Serial.peek() == 'g'){   //controls green color

            Serial.read();
            gVal = Serial.parseInt();
            analogWrite(gruenPin, gVal);
            EEPROM.write(1, gVal);
        }

        if(Serial.peek() == 'b'){   //controls blue color

            Serial.read();
            bVal = Serial.parseInt();
            analogWrite(blauPin, bVal);
            EEPROM.update(2, bVal);
        }

        if(Serial.peek() == 'f'){   //controls fading

            Serial.read();
            int fval = Serial.parseInt();
            if(fval==1){
                fadeOn = true;
            }
            if(fval==0){
                fadeOn = false;
                ersterLauf = true;
            }
            EEPROM.update(3,fval);
        }

        while(Serial.available() > 0){
            Serial.read();
        }
  }


    fade();

}




void fade(){    //fading function

// Blaue LED beim ersten Durchlauf einblenden

        if (ersterLauf == true && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause && fadeOn == true)
        {
          // Wenn b kleiner als 255 ist...
          if (b < 255)
          {
            b++;                      // Zählt b um 1 hoch
            analogWrite(blauPin, b);  // Ausganbe von b am LED Pin
            fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
          }

          // Wenn b bei 255 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
          if (b == 255 && (millis()- fadeZeit) > (fadePause + halteZeit))
          {
            ersterLauf = false;     // Erster Lauf ist abgeschlossen
          }
       }

        // Wenn ersterLauf abgeschlossen ist UND fadePause vergangen ist...
        if (ersterLauf == false && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause && fadeOn == true && fadeOn == true)
        {
          // Wechsel von Blau zu Lila 
          if (farbe == 'b')
          {
            // Wenn r kleiner als 255 ist...
            if (r < 255)
            {
              r++;                      // Zählt r um 1 hoch
              analogWrite(rotPin, r);   // Ausganbe von r am LED Pin
              fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
            }

            // Wenn r bei 255 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
            if (r == 255 && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause + halteZeit)
            {
              farbe = 'l';    // Ändere Frabe auf "l" (Lila)
            }
          }

            // Wechsel von Lila zu Rot
            if (farbe == 'l')
            {
               // Wenn b größer als 0 ist...
               if (b > 0)
              {
                b--;                      // Zählt b um 1 runter
                analogWrite(blauPin, b);  // Ausganbe von b am LED Pin
                fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
              }

              // Wenn b bei 0 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
              if (b == 0 && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause + halteZeit && fadeOn == true)
              {
                farbe = 'r';    // Ändere Frabe auf "r" (Rot)
               }
            }

            // Wechsel von Rot zu Gelb
            if (farbe == 'r')
            {
              // Wenn g kleiner als 255 ist...
              if (g < 255)
              {
              g++;                      // Zählt g um 1 hoch
              analogWrite(gruenPin, g);   // Ausganbe von g am LED Pin
              fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
              }

              // Wenn g bei 255 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
              if (g == 255 && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause + halteZeit && fadeOn == true)
             {
              farbe = 'y';    // Ändere Frabe auf "y" (Gelb)
             }
           }

           // Wechsel von Gelb zu Gruen
           if (farbe == 'y')
           {
              // Wenn r größer als 0 ist...
              if (r > 0)
              {
                r--;                      // Zählt r um 1 runter
                analogWrite(rotPin, r);   // Ausganbe von r am LED Pin
                fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
              }

              // Wenn r bei 0 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
              if (r == 0 && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause + halteZeit && fadeOn == true)
              {
                farbe = 'g';    // Ändere Frabe auf "g" (Grün)
              }
            }

          // Wechsel von Gruen zu Petrol
          if (farbe == 'g')
          {
            // Wenn b kleiner als 255 ist...
            if (b < 255)
            {
              b++;                      // Zählt b um 1 hoch
              analogWrite(blauPin, b);  // Ausganbe von b am LED Pin
              fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
            }

          // Wenn b bei 255 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
          if (b == 255 && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause + halteZeit && fadeOn == true)
          {
            farbe = 'p';    // Ändere Frabe auf "p" (Petrol)
          }
        }

        // Wechsel von Petrol zu Blau
        if (farbe == 'p')
        {
          // Wenn g größer als 0 ist...
          if (g > 0)
          {
            g--;                      // Zählt g um 1 runter
            analogWrite(gruenPin, g);   // Ausganbe von g am LED Pin
            fadeZeit  = millis();     // Aktuelle Zeit speichern
          }

       // Wenn g bei 0 angekommen UND die halteZeit vergangen ist...
       if (g == 0 && millis()- fadeZeit > fadePause + halteZeit && fadeOn == true)
       {
         farbe = 'b';    // Ändere Frabe auf "b" (Blau)
       }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you switch cables among red and blue? What happens if you print `rVal`?

Comment: if I switch the cables between blue and red the blue channel stops working as intended and when I print out rVal the correct value is printed

Comment: did you try using a different pwm pin, other than 11?

Comment: Well yeah thats what finally solved the problem. It seems like the IR-libary used a timer related to the one the pwm on Pin 11 is using. I connected it to Pin 5 now everythings fine.

Comment: add an answer to your own question with the solution then :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem just got solved. It seems like the IRremote Libary uses a timer related to the PWM-timer of pin 11. To solve this problem I just connected the Pin of the red color to another PWM-pin on the Nano (Pin 5) and now it works like a charm.

thanks for your help anyways :)